# What's $\omega_n$ in $\omega_n r^{n-1}$ for area of sphere?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spheres

What's $\omega_n$ in $\omega_n r^{n-1}$ for area of sphere?

Like what quantity is it?

Comment: If you take $r=1$, you see that is the area of the unit $n$-sphere. :)
Authors usually give it a name since it pops up as a normalization factor in many equations and transforms in PDEs and other fields of analysis I have no idea about.

Comment: The area (or rather circumference) of a circle is $2\pi r$, so we conclude $\omega_2=2\pi$. The area of a sphere is $\frac4\pi r^2$, so we conclude $\omega_3=4\pi$. For higher spheres, the "area" is again proportional to $r^{n-1}$, but the constants differ (just as they differ between the $n=2$ and the $n=3$ case)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I tried to find the recursive formula for the term $\omega_n$, but can't find it.

Comment: (I presume that if you're reading this from a book, backtracking a bit should give the answer!)

Comment: There are formulas in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778053/limit-of-n-1-measure-of-the-boundary-of-a-sphere and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174106/surface-area-of-the-sphere

Answer (score 1):

Given your formula, 
$$
\omega_n=\frac{n\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}
$$
a constant which depends only on the dimension of the ball and comes from the formula for the surface area of the n ball with radius $r$
$$
\frac{n\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}r^{n-1}
$$

Comment: This is right now except that you've changed from the notation in the OP for no particular good reason.

Comment: my particular reason is that I don't think the notation used by op is standard. It was right before with the notation i believe to be standard, although I dont have evan's on me

Comment: I've already linked this question to another one that uses OP's notation. Is there a standard or is this something that each author chooses?

Comment: if that's the case, I apologize and will edit my post accordingly

Comment: Evans uses $\alpha(n)$ for the volume of the $n$-sphere.

Comment: right ok, I recalled seeing $n(\text{constant which depends on dimension})r^{n-1}$  for the surface area of the n sphere. It appears that this is not as standard as I thought and I have edited my post accordingly